# Multiple select count() in one select from related tables

Tags: mysql, sql

For a example I have several related tables.

teachers table

```
tch_id
tch_name
```

students table

```
std_id
std_name
std_tch_id
```

lessons table

```
les_id
les_std_id
les_tch_id
```

I try select like:

```
select 
    tch_name,
    (select count(std_id) from students where std_tch_id = tch_id) as TotalStd,
    (select count(les_id) from lessons where les_tch_id = tch_id) as TotalLes
from teachers 
order by tch_id;
```

It works but maybe I am wrong or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks fine as it is (I would just recommend to prefix all field names with table aliases, for better readability and maintainability).

If you are looking to avoid the use of the inline subqueries to compute the total students and lessons, one solution would be to use an aggregated `JOIN`ed query, with `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` to compute the counts without duplicates:

```
SELECT t.tch_name, COUNT(DISTINCT s.std_id) TotalStd, COUNT(DISTINCT l.les_id) TotalLes
FROM teachers t
LEFT JOIN students s ON s.std_tch_id = t.tch_id
LEFT JOIN lessons  l ON l.les_tch_id = t.tch_id
GROUP BY t.tch_id, t.tch_name
ORDER BY t.tch_id
```

Whether or not this performs better than the original query really depends on your schema and data.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Like gmb said, there is nothing particularly wrong with your query; but as with most queries there are alternatives that have different performance characteristics. As is, The one I provide below will likely perform the same or better than yours. Your subqueries are correlated, meaning they will be likely re-executed for every result from the outer query; this one will only execute the subqueries once and then use indexes for relatively fast joins.

```
SELECT t.tch_name, tsc.sCount as TotalStd, tlc.lCount as TotalLes
FROM teachers AS t
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT std_tch_id AS tch_id, COUNT(std_id) AS sCount 
   FROM students 
   GROUP BY std_tch_id
) AS tsc ON t.tch_id = tsc.tch_id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT les_tch_id AS tch_id, COUNT(les_id) AS lCount 
   FROM lessons 
   GROUP BY les_tch_id
) AS tlc ON t.tch_id = tlc.tch_id
ORDER BY t.tch_id;
```

However, if the final query is somewhat different, yours could perform better. For example... If each table has a million rows, but the outer query has a WHERE condition that quickly narrows it down to a dozen rows from the `teacher` table, then executing your subqueries (that calculate the counts for a single teacher) a dozen times each may be cheaper than executing mine (that calculate counts for all teachers in the other two tables) once each.

In either case, making sure `teachers.tch_id`, `students.std_tch_id`, and `lessons.les_tch_id` are indexed is probably the most important factor for these queries